# Serve static site over https on nginx

Tags: nginx, https, static

My static site is not working over https, I don't know what is wrong, here is my sites config file:

```
server {
    listen 443 default ssl;

    root /var/www/site.com/site;
    index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    server_name site.com www.site.com;
    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/site.com/site.>
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/site.com/site.key;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

    location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }
```

}
server {

```
    listen 80;

    server_name _;

    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
```

}

Comment: Was it working with `http` and then you changed it and try `https`? If not, please try get a working solution with `http` first :) ...also what do you mean by "is not working"? Whats the HTTP error code?

Comment: @Geilmaker if I remove the redirection server block and put listen 80 in the one that's above it  works over http, also the error says This site can’t be reached

Comment: Are there any logs inside nginx? Sounds like nginx is not starting properly, so the site can't be reached. Have you tried just to use `listen 443 ssl;` and leave the `default` out?

Comment: @Geilmaker no nginx logs, and also tried without the default and is not working neither :(

Comment: @Geilmaker the problem was the firewall rules, now it's working, thanks